# For loop inside reactive function in Shiny

Tags: r, loops, vector, shiny, reactive

I met a problem with for loop in Shiny server and no one can find out how to fix it till now. I have been working on this for days but still didn't get any progress. Long story short, please just look at the following code. I was trying to fetch data from Google Finance and calculated the smoothed variance.

```
  stock2 <-
    reactive(
      getSymbols(
        toupper(input$ticker2),
        from = as.Date(input$date2[1]) - 150,
        to = input$date2[2],
        src = "google",
        auto.assign = F
      )
    )

  stock3 <- reactive(as.data.table(stock2()))
  stock <- reactive(as.data.frame(stock3()))
  stock.return <- reactive(diff(log(stock()[, 5])))
  stock.mu <- reactive(mean(stock.return()))
  stock.var <- reactive((stock.return() - stock.mu()) ^ 2)
  stock.var.smoothed <- reactive(rep(0, length(stock.return())))
```

Code above works totally fine and I have tested that.

So the problem is the following code, I want to assign a vector based on some calculation but I don't know the proper way to do it.

```
  stock.var.smoothed <- reactive({
    for (i in 2:length(stock.var())) {
      stock.var.smoothed[1] <<- stock.var()[1]
      stock.var.smoothed[i] <<-
        (1 - input$alpha) * stock.var.smoothed()[i - 1] + input$alpha * stock.var()[i]
    }
  })
```

The for loop doesn't work at all. 
The error code is

Error: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

But I already used () for the variables inside the function. So I have no idea how to fix that.

BTW, I also tried the following code

```
for (i in 2:length(stock.return())) {
  stock.momentum.smoothed[1] <- reactive(stock.momentum()[1])
  stock.momentum.smoothed[i] <-
    reactive((1 - input$beta) * stock.momentum.smoothed()[i - 1] + input$beta * stock.return()[i])
}
```

The error code is

Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)

I appreciate anyone that could give any help. Thank you!

Comment: `stock.var.smoothed` is a “reactive” object. In other words, it’s a function and, as R rightly says, you can’t subset it. You need to *call* it, and *then* subset the result.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Could you please tell me how to call it? I'm totally blank..

Comment: Or let's say how can I write a for loop for vectors in Shiny?

Comment: Without looking at it closely, I would definitely assign the results of `stock.var` to a temporary vector and use that inside your reactive. More efficient, easier to read, and less can go wrong.

Comment: Thanks Mike. But how can we do that? It seems we can only assign a vector within `reactive()` function. So what's the difference?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your subset assignment to the reactive (`stock.var.smoothed[1] <<-`) simply doesn’t make sense: this operation wouldn’t be what you want, even without the subsetting (it would replace your reactive object with a non-reactive value; i.e. it would stop being reactive).

You *can* create and assign to variables inside your reactive expression. But don’t assign to the global environment (i.e. don’t use `<<-`), and don’t try to reassign the reactive object itself. Instead, create a local temporary variable:

```
stock.var.smoothed <- reactive({
  value <- numeric(length(stock.var()))
  value[1] <- stock.var()[1]

  for (i in 2 : length(stock.var())) {
    value[i] <- (1 - input$alpha) * value[i - 1] + input$alpha * stock.var()[i]
  }

  value
})
```

Here, `value` could be any name (including `stock.var.smoothed` — but this would be a *different* variable than your reactive, because it’s in a different scope).

Furthermore, I’m pretty sure that this code be written without a loop and temporary variable (but it’s not immediately obvious how it would look like to me).

Finally, a note on code style: don’t use `.` inside variable names. This is confusing, since it’s also used for S3 dispatch to separate the method’s generic name and class name. A common convention in R is to use underscores instead (`stock_var_smoothed`).

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked and your explanation is very clear!