# Using numeric value inside of reactive context in a shiny app

Tags: r, loops, shiny, reactive-programming

I just started to look into shiny apps so most likely this is a very basic question, but after searching the forum I still could not get it too work.

As part of my very first app I have a simulated population of exactly 100000 cases from which I would like to draw n random samples, using a for loop.
So the general code would be something like:

```
samples<-list(NULL)
for(i in 1:100){samples[[i]]<-dplyr::sample_n(population, size=200, replace=FALSE)}
```

Now I want to include a slider, that replaces the 100 in the for loop, so that the user can decide how many samples to draw.
However, when defining the slider in the UI and then trying the following on the server side

```
samples<-list(NULL)
for(i in 1:input$n_samples){samples[[i]]<-dplyr::sample_n(population, size=200, replace=FALSE)}
```

I receive the following error:

> Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() :  Operation not
>   allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something
>   that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)

Next I've tried

```
samples <- reactive({   
samples<-list(NULL)
for(i in 1:input$n_samples){samples[[i]]<-dplyr::sample_n(population, size=200, replace=FALSE)}     
})
```

and version with reactiveVal(), and reactiveValues() and all kinds of variations but without success.

So basically, all I want is that the value which the user selects through the slider determines the number of repetitions in my for loop.

I've also saw this thread but couldn't figure out if this is a similar problem:
[For loop inside reactive function in Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46118166/for-loop-inside-reactive-function-in-shiny)
Hope someone can shed a bit of light on this.

Comment: Try using `observer({})` or use one of the output functions, i.e. `renderPlot`, `renderDataTable`...

Comment: Your second attempt is a good way to go. But you need to return the list : `samples <- reactive({ out <- vector("list", input$n_samples) \\ for(i in 1:length(out)){out[[i]] <- ......} \\ out })`. I use "\\" to mean a line break (we cannot do line breaks in comments). Then do `samples()` in a reactive context to get this list.

Answer (score 0):

They say that growing lists is a bad idea in R. You should pre-allocate your list and fill the spaces iteratively. The following app will do that.

Based on a population (`mtcars`), changing the slider triggers drawing as many samples of 10 values as the slider value says. The result can be read by calling `samples()`. Each time the slider changes, `samples()` updates (note: not `samples`, which is merely a function, but `samples()` which is the result of the function call, the drawn samples):

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

population <- mtcars


ui <- fluidPage(h4("You have a population of", nrow(population), "values. Choose the number of random sample sets"),
                h5("(each sample contains 10 values):"),
                sliderInput("n", "Number of samples", min=1, max = 1000, value = 5),
                textOutput("summary"))


server <- function(input, output) {

    # a normal function that draws a sample of 10 values
    draw_single_sample <- function(x) sample_n(population, size = 10)

    # A reactive function that takes slider value and produce as many samples as the slider requests
    samples <- reactive(lapply(1:input$n, draw_single_sample))

    # Dependend on samples (thus input$n), print the result of the random draw
    output$summary <- renderText({
        samples_concrete <- samples()
        paste("Finished calculation. You have", length(samples_concrete),
              "random samples of 10 values each Mean values of the first columns:",
              toString(sapply(samples_concrete, function(x) mean(x[[1]]))))
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```